# Where can I find the new Tails 3.2 checksum?

Tags: security, tails, linux

I'm looking for the new Tails 3.2 checkums (md5, sha1, sha256, etc).
It seems that there is no way to find it in its own site. Even googling it brings not much information. So there is something I'm losing in the site, somewhere that I should search for it?

ps: I know there are safest ways to check the iso but I just wanna use the checksum anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
https://tails.boum.org/contribute/build/reproducible/#index2h3

And you will find a link to the SHA-256 checksum of the latest ISO image.

Answer (score 0):

Tails doesn't publish the hashes of the .iso in such a manner because it's always more secure to verify the signature. Users who are unfamiliar, unwilling or unable to use PGP are offered different means to fetch and verify the ISO through the installation guide.

As such, there is no official place where you will be able to find it.

Verifying the signature is the same as verifying the hash, since the signature is just a signed copy of the SHA512 hash of the .iso file, which also verifies the publisher of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in 2020, Tails now provides the SHA256 checksum hashes for its latest images in the form of a json file at: https://tails.boum.org/install/v2/Tails/amd64/stable/latest.json

These checksums are used to enable verification of images by way of the javascript verification tool (see [step 2/4 on the image download page](https://tails.boum.org/install/download/index.en.html)) that Tails rolled out in 2020.  See the links below for more info:

https://tails.boum.org/news/verification_extension_deprecation/index.en.html

https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/download_verification/